# Multiple production ruby/rails environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I would like to know if it's possible to set specific ruby environments to specific sites.

In /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/passenger-2.2.15/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/passenger-2.2.15
PassengerRuby /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/bin/ruby
```

But say I want to use a different ruby environment, for a specific site, how would I go about doing this?

I have rvm installed correctly for my user 'user' so switching environments and installing other environments is quite painless, but the apache configuration side has me clueless.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [RVM Passenger page](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/passenger/):

> Q: Can I run multiple projects under
>   passenger with each project on a
>   different ruby version?
>
> A: Not at this time. Passenger
>   currently only supports running it's
>   projects under *one* ruby. You can get
>   this behavior using a proxy pass.

If you want different ruby environments per project, you'll need to use mongrel/unicorn/etc.